# next JS Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Cancel rendering route

Tags: javascript, next.js, router

I'm getting `Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Cancel rendering route`

I have this function on my navBar:

```
const userData={
    id:1,
    email: "",
    name: "",
    lastName: "",
    photo: "",
    token: "",
    onLine: false
}

const router = useRouter();
const logOut = () => {
    dispatch( setUserLogged(userData) )
    router.push('/');
}
```

I call `import { useRouter } from 'next/router';`  of course.

button

```
<Link href="#" onClick={()=>logOut()} >
   Log out
</Link>
```

so, on my navBar I have the option "Log out", this work for close session, so, when I clicked on Button `Log Out`, this button call the function `logOut` then I'm getting `Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Cancel rendering route`

what is causing this error???

Comment: Can you add the codes related to your dispatch call and your logout button?

Comment: get it, I updated

Comment: Can you also add your logout button JSX codes?

Comment: get it, I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called `router.push` on a `Link` tag without preventing its event and it made this error.

For solution add `e.preventDefault() to your` Link` tag like this:

```
<Link href="#" onClick={(e)=> {
 e.preventDefault();
 logOut();
} >
 Log out
</Link>
```